# Animação ao tocar no botão

Tags: java, android, animação

Tenho uma tela de cadastro, onde já está definido uma foto padrão. 
Se eu pressionar em cima da foto ele abre 2 opções para mudar a foto. Ou pega pela galeria ou tira uma foto.

Ao clicar no botão gostaria de colocar um efeito. 
Por favor, alguém pode me dar um dica ?

[image: Imagem sem botões]
[image: Imagem com botões]

Answer (score 3):

Segue abaixo uma forma bem básica e simples possível de implementação. Lembrando que para criar uma animação, depende muito da criatividade. Então se quiser fazer coisas mirabolantes, vai ter que que fazer bastante pesquisa. No exemplo de código abaixo, é criado um `ImageView` no qual após o click aparecerá outros dois `ImageButton` na sequencia, que seria um `btnFotoGaleria` e outro `btnFotoCamera`.

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity{

    ImageView btnFotoPerfil;
    ImageButton btnFotoGaleria;
    ImageButton btnFotoCamera;

    // Animação
    Animation animFadein;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnFotoGaleria= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFotoGaleria);
        btnFotoCamera= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFotoCamera);

        // load the animation
        animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.fade_in); 

        btnFotoPerfil= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnFotoPerfil);
        // evento onclick no botao
        btnFotoPerfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnFotoGaleria.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnFotoCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // start the animation
                btnFotoGaleria.startAnimation(animFadein);
                btnFotoCamera.startAnimation(animFadein);
            }
        });       
    }
}
```

É importante lembrar de configurar nos parâmetros das `ImageButton` definindo como `android:visibility="gone"` para que eles permaneçam invisíveis até o click do usuário.

Dentro do `res` é necessário criar um diretório com nome `anim` e um `.xml` para sua animação, por exemplo `fade_in.xml` com o seguinte código abaixo:

#### fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

#### Detalhes

- [Android Working with XML Animations](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)